# Controlling the size of tables produced from the R functions tabular() and latex()

Tags: tables, r

I'll state up front that I'm not absolutely certain whether this question is more appropriate for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or for this site.  However, since I've seen several questions about the `latex()` command from `Hmisc` here, I think this question is suitable for this site.

I'm a relatively experienced `R` user but pretty new to `LaTeX`.  I am trying to automatically create a large number of pdfs from a set of results generated within `R`.  I'd prefer to create these files entirely within `R`, if possible.  After some searching, I decided to do this through a combination of the [`tables`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tables/vignettes/tables.pdf) package and the `latex()` function from [`Hmisc`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/Hmisc.pdf).

Some of the tables I'm creating are quite large, and so when I examine the pdfs that I've created, the tables tend to run off the page.  What I'd like to do is use either the `latex()` command or the `tabular()` command within `R` to shrink the size of the tables that appear on my resulting pdfs.  The `latex` function has a "`size`" argument, but specifying `size = "small"` doesn't appear to work with tables generated by calls to `tabular()`.  Does anyone have any advice?

Some sample code can be found below.

```r
require(tables)
require(Hmisc)

# Create sample data
Condition <- factor(rep(c("Control", "Experimental"), 150))
Time <- factor(rep(c("Baseline", "Baseline", "Three days", "Three days", 
   "Three weeks", "Three weeks"), 50))
var1 <- rnorm(300)
var2 <- rnorm(300)
var3 <- rnorm(300)
var4 <- rnorm(300)
var5 <- rnorm(300)
var6 <- rnorm(300)

# Add to data frame, sprinkle in missing values
d <- data.frame(Condition, Time, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
d[sample(1:300, 30), c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")] <- NA
d[sample(1:300, 20), c("var5", "var6")] <- NA

# Create helper functions
mean.narm <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
sd.narm <- function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
count.obs <- function(x) sum(!is.na(x))
# Use tabular() from tables
tab <- tabular((Heading("Variable 1") * var1 + Heading("Variable 2") * var2 + 
   Heading("Variable 3") * var3 + Heading("Variable 4") * var4 + Heading("Variable 5") * var5 + 
   Heading("Variable 6") * var6) * Time ~ Condition * ((N=count.obs) + (Mean=mean.narm) + (SD=sd.narm)),
           data = d)

# Ensure that pdflatex is used when I call latex(), below
options(latexcmd = "pdflatex")
options(dviExtension = "pdf")
options(xdvicmd = "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/bin/i386/open.exe")
# Use the latex() function
latex(tab, "table1.tex")
```

Edit: As requested, below is the code obtained from a call to `latex(tab, "")`.  As I mentioned above, what I want to do is not just manually modify the LaTeX produced by the `latex()` function, but to ensure that the LaTeX code generated from the call to `latex()` produces a smaller table.

```
\begin{tabular}{llcccccc}
\hline
& & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Condition} \\ 
& & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Control} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Experimental} \\ 
 & Time & N & Mean & SD & N & Mean & \multicolumn{1}{c}{SD} \\ 
\hline
Variable 1 & Baseline  & $42$ & $\phantom{-}0.029831$ & $1.0657$ & $46$ & $\phantom{-}0.0067612$ & $1.0687$ \\
 & Three days  & $44$ & $\phantom{-}0.109871$ & $1.0161$ & $43$ & $-0.1633312$ & $1.1552$ \\
 & Three weeks  & $47$ & $\phantom{-}0.160282$ & $1.0613$ & $48$ & $\phantom{-}0.1055877$ & $0.9537$ \\
Variable 2 & Baseline  & $42$ & $-0.166005$ & $1.1078$ & $46$ & $\phantom{-}0.0012202$ & $0.9659$ \\
 & Three days  & $44$ & $-0.205125$ & $0.9315$ & $43$ & $-0.2294237$ & $1.0693$ \\
 & Three weeks  & $47$ & $-0.164718$ & $1.0122$ & $48$ & $-0.0769583$ & $1.0418$ \\
Variable 3 & Baseline  & $42$ & $\phantom{-}0.077019$ & $1.0643$ & $46$ & $\phantom{-}0.0798812$ & $1.0396$ \\
 & Three days  & $44$ & $-0.282688$ & $0.9023$ & $43$ & $\phantom{-}0.1299074$ & $0.9916$ \\
 & Three weeks  & $47$ & $-0.291495$ & $1.0138$ & $48$ & $-0.0240293$ & $1.0309$ \\
Variable 4 & Baseline  & $42$ & $-0.247300$ & $1.0963$ & $46$ & $-0.0409480$ & $1.0901$ \\
 & Three days  & $44$ & $-0.158524$ & $1.0995$ & $43$ & $\phantom{-}0.1486800$ & $0.8722$ \\
 & Three weeks  & $47$ & $-0.149038$ & $0.8798$ & $48$ & $-0.0002842$ & $0.9750$ \\
Variable 5 & Baseline  & $49$ & $\phantom{-}0.008081$ & $0.8102$ & $47$ & $-0.3131353$ & $1.0592$ \\
 & Three days  & $45$ & $-0.241864$ & $1.0037$ & $45$ & $\phantom{-}0.1130470$ & $0.8106$ \\
 & Three weeks  & $44$ & $-0.177473$ & $1.0706$ & $50$ & $-0.0264635$ & $0.7805$ \\
Variable 6 & Baseline  & $49$ & $\phantom{-}0.013659$ & $1.0833$ & $47$ & $-0.0967571$ & $1.0676$ \\
 & Three days  & $45$ & $\phantom{-}0.098045$ & $0.9842$ & $45$ & $\phantom{-}0.0756736$ & $0.9613$ \\
 & Three weeks  & $44$ & $-0.152400$ & $1.0654$ & $50$ & $-0.2145893$ & $1.0157$ \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: could you post the generated latex for those of us who don't have R to hand? the latex command `\small` before the table should make it smaller or you can make a multi-page table with longtable or supertabular instead of tabular.

Comment: Can't help with the R but if you can get it to put `\small` (or `\tiny` or `\footnotesize`  immediately before `\begin{tabular}` then it would be smaller.

Comment: The `latex()` function produces a `tabular` in a `.tex` file. Since you are using `tables` package, you must be working on a `sweave` file, with `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}...\end{document}` and the works. Then you can enclose the  `R` chunk in `{}` and just before the chunk, write `\small`, like `{\small <<results=tex>>= R code @}`. Compiling using Sweave, you will get better pdf output. To produce better results, you can also use `booktabs` package so that you can use `booktabs()` to typeset your tables.

Comment: @hpesoj626, I am not using `Sweave`, but instead am doing all my calls from an `R` file. right now, I'm trying to figure out whether I can change the size of the table I produce entirely within `R` using `latex()` or a similar function.  Would I be better off abandoning `R` for `Sweave` for creating my tables?  My goal is to create code that both be automated and easily adapted to other problems, since I need to produce high-quality statistical tables pretty often for my work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `tables` package of `R`, you must be using `Sweave`. Here is a `.Rnw` file that might work for you. I don't have that much background with `R`. I just use it for some basic statistical computations. So I am sorry if I can't give you a definite answer whether you can set up the size of the table using the `latex()` command. If that were your only option, I would suggest asking in [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Save this as `foobar.Rnw` and put it in your working directory. Now, in R, set your working directory using `setwd()` (if  you haven't yet). Now, run

```
Sweave("foobar.Rnw")
```

If you are successful doing this, you should see

```
You can now run (pdf)latex on ‘tableprosweave.tex’
```

at the end.

Now, in your working directory, open `foobar.tex` with your favorite TeX editor and run `pdflatex` or just run

```
pdflatex foobar
```

in your terminal/command line.

`foobar.Rnw`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE, keep.source=TRUE}
<<echo=false>>=
options(width=60)
@

<<>>=
require(tables)
require(Hmisc)

booktabs() % To use booktabs formatting

# Create sample data
Condition <- factor(rep(c("Control", "Experimental"), 150))
Time <- factor(rep(c("Baseline", "Baseline", "Three days", "Three days", 
   "Three weeks", "Three weeks"), 50))
var1 <- rnorm(300)
var2 <- rnorm(300)
var3 <- rnorm(300)
var4 <- rnorm(300)
var5 <- rnorm(300)
var6 <- rnorm(300)

# Add to data frame, sprinkle in missing values
d <- data.frame(Condition, Time, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
d[sample(1:300, 30), c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")] <- NA
d[sample(1:300, 20), c("var5", "var6")] <- NA

# Create helper functions
mean.narm <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
sd.narm <- function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)
count.obs <- function(x) sum(!is.na(x))
# Use tabular() from tables

tab <- tabular((Heading("Variable 1") * var1 + Heading("Variable 2") * var2 + 
   Heading("Variable 3") * var3 + Heading("Variable 4") * var4 + Heading("Variable 5") * var5 + 
   Heading("Variable 6") * var6) * Time ~ Condition * ((N=count.obs) + (Mean=mean.narm) + (SD=sd.narm)),
           data = d)
@

\newpage

% Here, \small was written just before the code chunk.

\begin{center}
\small
<<results=tex,echo=FALSE>>=
latex(
tab
)
@
\end{center}

\vfill

% Here, \scriptsize was written just before the code chunk.

\begin{center}
\scriptsize
<<results=tex,echo=FALSE>>=
latex(
tab
)
@
\end{center}

%<<>>=
%# Ensure that pdflatex is used when I call latex(), below
%options(latexcmd = "pdflatex")
%options(dviExtension = "pdf")
%options(xdvicmd = "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/bin/i386/open.exe")
%# Use the latex() function
%#latex(tab, file="table1.tex")
%@

\end{document}
```

I have commented out the last lines as I really don't know what they do and to get the file to compile in my computer `:-)` Here is the second page output.

[image]

If you really are just after the table output, I suggest that you just write `\small` or `\footnotesize`, etc, before the code chunk. Again, I don't know how to do this with just the `latex()` function of `R`. See [`manual`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/doc/Sweave.pdf) for more information about `Sweave`.

Some editors make you edit and compile `.Rnw` directly from source such as [Rstudio](http://www.rstudio.com/). AFAIK, [`Texmaker`](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) can also handle it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice answer (+1).  It actually looks like I might be able to do my desired automation within the `R` code chunk.  This isn't a solution that had occurred to me (as I mentioned, I'm very new to LaTeX).  `:)`

Comment: See my edit since I forgot to incorporate `booktabs()` function for better-looking tables and explanation about editors.